# Why dagger2? we can create required class objects manually and injects

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I got know about the Android dependency injection from https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection . the thing is without dagger2 we can create object like below and use it(**Constructor Injection**). what make sense to use Dagger2? The benefit of Design pattern to archive the below benefits

1. Ease of Testing
2. Reusability of Code
3. Ease of Refactoring

but my question is without Dagger-2 also we can achieve this. then what should we want to use Dagger2?

> Without Dagger2

Engine

```
public class Engine {

    public Engine()
    {

    }
}
```

Wheels

```
public class Wheels {

    public Wheels()
    {

    }
}
```

Car

```
public class Car {
    private static final String TAG = "Car";

    private Engine engine;
    private Wheels wheels;

    public Car(Engine engine,Wheels wheels)
    {
        this.engine=engine;
        this.wheels=wheels;
    }

    public void drive()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "driving");
    }


}
```

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Car car;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        Engine engine=new Engine();
//        Wheels wheels=new Wheels();

        car=new Car(new Engine(),new Wheels());

        car.drive();

    }
}
```

> With Dagger-2

Engine

```
public class Engine {
    
    @Inject
    public Engine()
    {

    }
}
```

Wheels

```
public class Wheels {

    @Inject
    public Wheels()
    {

    }
}
```

Car

```
public class Car {
    private static final String TAG = "Car";

    private Engine engine;
    private Wheels wheels;

    @Inject
    public Car(Engine engine,Wheels wheels)
    {
        this.engine=engine;
        this.wheels=wheels;
    }

    public void drive()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "driving");
    }


}
```

CarComponent

```
@component
public interface CarComponent{
   Car getCar();
}
```

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Car car;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CarComponent carComponent=DaggerCarComponent.create();
        carComponent.getCar();
        car.drive();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your own example, it should be quite obvious:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    car=new Car(new Engine(),new Wheels());

    car.drive();
}
```

so here, you have to make a new instance of `Engine`, and a new instance of `Wheels` every single time you want to get an intance of car. so let's consider:

what happens if car now needs a new component as a parameter ?

you'll have to add this dependency into every single creation of the car object.

```
car=new Car(new Engine(),new Wheels(), new Foo()); <-- you'll be doing this throughout your entire project.
```

let's consider what happens if your dependencies have dependencies themselves:

```
car=new Car(new Engine("some value", "another value"),new Wheels(SomeComplicatedObjectWithMoreDependencies()));
```

so you'll end up having to create a ton of dependencies before you can create the object that you want, and you'll be doing this everywhere in your project, every single time, which is the point of using a dependency injection/inversion framework (this doesn't have anything to do with dagger, this is a general thing) - to help you manage your dependencies.

Comment: I got your point. But in above `without dagger-2` Car method. i did like that. only getting the `Wheels` and `Engine` instance in the constructer `public Car(Engine engine,Wheels wheels)` . I'm asking we can inject object instance manually why Dagger-2 needed?

Comment: @Prasath of course, dagger (or any other dependency injection framework) won't do something which you can't do yourself. technically, no library will do something you can't do yourself, libraries make it easier to do something. making use of a dependency injection framework just makes it easier, but it depends on your project. you don't _have_ to use anything